# audio_play on turtlebot: messages being sent, but no audio output

Tags: ros, audio, audio-common

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get audio streaming back from my turtlebot and was delighted to find the audio_common package which provides audio_play and audio_capture.  Sadly, it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm following the tutorial found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/audio_common/Tutorials/Streaming%20audio

**Setup**

- On my turtlebot, I installed sound_common with "apt-get install ros-electric-sound-drivers"
- My microphone and speakers are configured correctly, I'm able to record and play back sounds.
- The command to test my audio setup works.  It echos sounds from the microphone.

```
gst-launch-0.10 alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

- I launched both audio_capture and audio_play as per the tutorial

```
$ roslaunch audio_capture capture.launch
$ roslaunch audio_play play.launch
```

**Problem and Troubleshooting**

- No sound output.
- Both scripts launched without error.
- I've verified that the nodes are connected using rxgraph
- "rostopic echo audio" streams audio messages.
- I can see the microphone input level bouncing, but the output level is doing nothing.
- I've used sound_play to verify that I can play sounds and my volume settings are correct.

From what I can tell, everything should be working.  But I still get no output.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks,

-Brian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12777/audio_play-on-turtlebot:-messages-being-sent,-but-no-audio-output/) by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried the example in the [turtlebot_sounds](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_sounds) package?

---

Originally posted by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) with karma: 3248 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-01-31**:
hmm... thanks for the suggestion, I'll look at that.  any suggestions for troubleshooting codec issues?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-28**:
Your problem is likely that audo_play cannot process the audio you have chosen due to a codec issue.

**Comment by [brianpen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1638/brianpen/) on 2012-01-27**:
Yes, it works correctly and plays the sounds.

**Comment by [mathijsdelangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/11976/mathijsdelangen/) on 2014-02-24**:
Have you been able to solve this problem? I am having the same kind of issues at the moment using audio_play. However, in the beginning I have sound playback, but it stops after a little while.